# can any one explain and provide the correct the code?

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML file has:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <script style="text/css" src=".\Scripts\CSS\tryc.css"></script>
        <script style="text/javascript" src=".\Scripts\JavaScripts\Text8.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
         <h1 id="heading1">Coming Soon</h1> 
        <object id="circle-svg" width="1300" height="560" type="image/svg+xml" data=".\Scripts\svg\ulti.svg"></object>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript has

```
window.onload = function () {
    var as = document.getElementById("body");
    var as1 = as.getElementById("heading1");
    as1.style.color = "blue";
    alert(as1);
    alert("try");
};
```

The text does not turn blue.

Comment: Please format for easier reading?

Comment: On a side note, you need to use the `<link>` tag to include a CSS file, not a `<script>` tag (and you will use the `href` attribute in it, instead of the `src` attribute in the `script`).

Comment: Note: If you used the console (F12 in many browsers) you would have seen an error message that would have answered your question `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLBodyElement> has no method 'getElementById'`

Answer (score 8):

`getElementById` must always be called from a `document` object.

```
var as = document.getElementById("body");
var as1 = as.getElementById("heading1");
var as1 = document.getElementById("heading1");
```

No nested context is needed, because IDs must be unique within the document.

---

And FWIW, you can use `document.body` instead of putting an ID on the body.

---

Oh, also you should use forward slashes instead of backslashes to get your script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/JavaScripts/Text8.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can use

```
as.getElementById();
```

Why dont you go directly with:

```
as = document.getElementById('heading1'); 
as.style.color = 'blue';
```